# Set Meteor dynamic template Name in ViewModel binding

Tags: templates, meteor, viewmodel

I have following template which use Tempalte.dynamic helper to render dynamic template.

```
    <template name="links">
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{> Template.dynamic template=viewTypeTemplate data=links}}
        </div>
   </template>
```

This works find if i use viewTypeTemplate variable as Template helper as below.

```
Template.links.helpers({
   viewTypeTemplate: function () {
        return Session.get('isThumbView') ? 'linkThumbList' : 'linkList';
    }
});
```

But it does not work i user Meteor Viewmodel binding variable instead of Template helper variable.

```
Template.links.viewmodel({
    isThumbView: false,
    viewTypeTemplate: function(){
      return this.isThumbView()? 'linkThumbList' : 'linkList';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Template.links.viewmodel({
    isThumbView: false,
    viewTypeTemplate: function(){
      return this.isThumbView()? 'linkThumbList' : 'linkList';
   }
},'viewTypeTemplate');
```

Expose `viewTypeTemplate` as helper to use publicly.
for multiple helpers

```
Template.links.viewmodel({
        isThumbView: false,
        viewTypeTemplate: function(){
          return this.isThumbView()? 'linkThumbList' : 'linkList';
       }
},['viewTypeTemplate','isThumbView']);
```

explore more at [Here](http://viewmodel.meteor.com/)